# How to convert pandas DataFrame to tensorflow data?

Tags: pandas, tensorflow

Theoretically, this is supposed to work:

```
tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(X, y=y, shuffle=True)
```

But yields opaque error like:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert value CategoricalDtype(categories=[...],
             ordered=False) to a TensorFlow DType.
```

Where is the 100% example for this. I have constructed categorical and identity and embedded features for these. Not sure if that is needed.

Comment: This is just categoricals. They are not handled by tensorflow. Seems like a miss.

Answer (score -1):

This is just categoricals. They are not handled by tensorflow. Seems like a miss.